# pyspark RDD count nodes in a DAG

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

I have RDD which shows up as

```
["2\t{'3': 1}",
 "3\t{'2': 2}",
 "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
 "5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
 "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}",
 "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
 "10\t{'5': 1}",
 "11\t{'5': 2}"]
```

I could split it up and am able to count the nodes before the '\t' or i can write a function to count the nodes on the right. This is a weighet DAG. If i count by hand, I see there are 11 nodes. but am unable to figure out how to bring the node 1 on right side into the nodes before I do distinct and count. My code is

```
`import ast
def break_nodes(line):
    data_dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
    
    # Iterate through the dictionary items and print them
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        print(f'key {key} val {value}')
        yield (int(key))
        
    
nodeIDs = dataRDD.map(lambda line: line.split('\t')) \
                    .flatMap(lambda x: break_nodes(x[1])) \
                    .distinct()`
```

This just counts the node from the right of \t. I have code for left side which is very simple

```
`nodeIDs = dataRDD.flatMap(lambda line: line.split('\t')[0])
totalCount = nodeIDs.distinct().count()`
```

What modification can I do to the code to get all the nodes counted? My brain is fried trying so many ways

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `flatMap` to find all the nodes in the rdd then use `distinct` to get the unique nodes

```
import ast

def find_all(r):
    x, y = r.split('\t')
    return [x, *ast.literal_eval(y).keys()]

nodes = dataRDD.flatMap(find_all).distinct()
```

---

```
nodes.collect()
# ['4', '5', '10', '2', '1', '9', '3', '6', '7', '8', '11']

nodes.count()
# 11
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. one dumb question. Since we are evaluating the string as a set with ast, when we put the keys in the list, wouldnt there be duplicates? I see the result doesnt show any duplicates but i want to understand how come.

Comment: The list might contain duplicates but as you see we are chaining `flatMap` with `distinct` method to remove the dupes, for instance if you execute `dataRDD.flatMap(find_all).collect()` the result will contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If value after `\t` is correct JSON, string can be split, second part parsed to Map (Python dict), and keys and values added to result. On Scala:

```
val df = Seq("2\t{'3': 1}",
  "3\t{'2': 2}",
  "4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}",
  "5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}",
  "6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}",
  "7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
  "8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
  "9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}",
  "10\t{'5': 1}",
  "11\t{'5': 2}").toDF("value")

val disassembled = df
  .withColumn("splitted", split($"value", "\t"))
  // take first and last parts
  .withColumn("beginning", $"splitted".getItem(0))
  .withColumn("json", $"splitted".getItem(1))
  // convert to Map
  .withColumn("map", from_json(col("json"), MapType(StringType, StringType)))

disassembled.show(false)

val result = disassembled.select($"beginning".alias("ids"))
  .union(disassembled.select(explode(map_keys($"map"))))
  .union(disassembled.select(explode(map_values($"map"))))
  .distinct()
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+
|value                      |splitted                     |beginning|json                    |map                     |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+
|2\t{'3': 1}                |[2, {'3': 1}]                |2        |{'3': 1}                |{3 -> 1}                |
|3\t{'2': 2}                |[3, {'2': 2}]                |3        |{'2': 2}                |{2 -> 2}                |
|4\t{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |[4, {'1': 1, '2': 1}]        |4        |{'1': 1, '2': 1}        |{1 -> 1, 2 -> 1}        |
|5\t{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|[5, {'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}]|5        |{'4': 3, '2': 1, '6': 1}|{4 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 6 -> 1}|
|6\t{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |[6, {'2': 1, '5': 2}]        |6        |{'2': 1, '5': 2}        |{2 -> 1, 5 -> 2}        |
|7\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |[7, {'2': 1, '5': 1}]        |7        |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |{2 -> 1, 5 -> 1}        |
|8\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |[8, {'2': 1, '5': 1}]        |8        |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |{2 -> 1, 5 -> 1}        |
|9\t{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |[9, {'2': 1, '5': 1}]        |9        |{'2': 1, '5': 1}        |{2 -> 1, 5 -> 1}        |
|10\t{'5': 1}               |[10, {'5': 1}]               |10       |{'5': 1}                |{5 -> 1}                |
|11\t{'5': 2}               |[11, {'5': 2}]               |11       |{'5': 2}                |{5 -> 2}                |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+------------------------+------------------------+

+---------+
|ids      |
+---------+
|6        |
|4        |
|3        |
|2        |
|5        |
|10       |
|8        |
|11       |
|7        |
|9        |
|1        |
+---------+
```

Note: RDD mentioned in question, but can be converted to DataFrame easily.